# Update post "A" on comment submition on post "B"

Tags: comments, comment-form, wp-update-post

Hello and thanks in advance for any help. Im trying to update the post status from a post when submiting a comment on other post, I have a variable in the url pointing to the ID of the post I want to update like so mysite.com/some-post/?id=1234

Hooking into 'comment_post' wont get the variable, so a new post is created insted of updating

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'aa_comment_update_post' );

function aa_comment_update_post( $comment_ID ) {

   $id = $_GET['id'];

   $postarr = array(
      'ID'            => $id,
      'post_status'   => 'draft',
   );

  wp_update_post( $postarr );

}
```

Any idea would be much appreciated

Comment: What exactly isn't working with this approach? What do you mean 'comment_post won't get the variable' ?

Comment: The hook 'comment_post'  wich hooks after a comment is posted doesnt get the variable value in the url /?id=1234 wich is present in the url where the comment will be posted. I suppose it's something to do with the time at which the hook sends headers info.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/

Comment: Not totally with you, as hooks don't 'get' URL query parameters like that? Do you mean that for some reason $_GET['id'] isn't set? It definitely should be if that is your URL, so if it's not then something else is happening. It's not related to where you're calling it from though.

Comment: In example, this other hook 'comment_form_before' gets the variable,query parameter as you mention. $_GET['id'] is set and gets its value in the callback function but not with  'comment_post'

I hope this gist helps to understand https://gist.github.com/Aeonexe/f92a296c9576a270867195d7fe557a35


By the way thank you for your time @mozboz

Comment: But both those calls happen in the same page? That sounds really weird to me, and it probably means that somewhere in the code $_GET['id'] is getting altered. So some ideas for what you could do: 1. in a place where you do have it, put it in a global so that you can get it elsewhere and not have to solve this weird problem. 2. if it's possible, try changing the name of the ID parameter, or add your own parameter. this might work around the issue of something removing it.